# Is there way to format code with line-breaks and indentation produced by ExpressionToCode

Tags: c#, .net, code-generation, code-formatting

Is there way to format code produced by [ExpressionToCode](https://github.com/EamonNerbonne/ExpressionToCode)? In particular to add line-breaks and indentation as following:

```
var code = ExpressionToCode.ToCode(() => new A(new B(), new C()));
```

and the result code is:

```
() => 
    new A(
        new B(),
        new C())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really. You could take the Roslyn `SyntaxTree` (using `ToSyntaxTree` instead of `ToCode`) and use that to format the output any way you want.

It's actually quite easy to handle code formatting with Roslyn - you just have to inherit your own class from `SyntaxRewriter`. See http://www.christophdebaene.com/blog/2011/10/26/roslyn-formatting-code/ for more information.

The problem of code formatting is actually quite complex, it needs quite a bit of thought.